# How to properly add JTextField components in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield

I have a panel that contains *different* components (JLabel, JButton, JTextComponent, etc). I want to get the list of **JTextField** in this way:

```
ArrayList<JTextField> arrayTf = new ArrayList();
Component[] arrayComponent = this.getComponents();
for (Component c : arrayComponent )
{   
    if (c instanceof JTextField ) {
        arrayTf.add(c);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure that's the right way . Please tell me this is the right way ? Or is there an easier way? Thank U.

Comment: This seems like a pretty standard way of accomplishing this. What would make you think its wrong?

Comment: .NET people would use LINQ here :P

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Java people can use stream. I don't know what's a point of your comment.

Comment: @Obicere, I thought that there is an easier way than this .

Comment: @ Branislav Lazic I have no ideas :)

Comment: One alternative is to override all the `add` and `remove` methods to cache the text fields. If you do this, be sure to call the super method as well though. This would work better if it is being called a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is the simplest way.

However, if you want to get fancy then you can use Darryl's [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/). The basic code would be:

```
List<JTextField> components = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTextField.class, this, false);
```

The benefit of this class is that it is reusable. So you could easily get all the JButtons in one line without writing more code. Also, this code allows you to get components on the specified panel or the panel and all nested panels. There are a few other features as well.